# How to change ScrollBar color in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, scrollbar

I've tried to customize ScrollBar using `contentItem` but the ScrollBar doesn't display in this case. Are there any other ways to change ScrollBar color?

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill        : parent
    ScrollBar.vertical  : ScrollBar {
                        anchors.rightMargin: 10 * AppTheme.scaleValue
                        contentItem: Rectangle {
                            color: "red"
                        }
    }
    boundsBehavior      : Flickable.StopAtBounds
    currentIndex        : 0
    focus               : true
    clip                : true
    model               : checkDataModel


    delegate: Rectangle {
        id      : rect
        width   : onlineChecksUpperPanel.width - 15 * AppTheme.scaleValue
        height  : 40 * AppTheme.scaleValue
        color   : index % 2 == 0 ? "#ECEEF1" : "#FFFFFF"
        Text {
            text                : checkNum
            font.family         : AppTheme.fontBold.name
            font.pixelSize      : AppTheme.textSizePxSmaller
            textFormat          : Text.StyledText
            color               : AppTheme.textColorTouchDark
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            leftPadding: 16 * AppTheme.scaleValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is an `implicitWidth` on the `contentItem`. It needs to know what size to draw the scrollbar. It will work fine like this:

```
ScrollBar.vertical  : ScrollBar {
    anchors.rightMargin: 10 * AppTheme.scaleValue
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 6
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! If this resolves your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The below code is ok for me. maybe a variable does not exist in your source code and the viewer can not render the item.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ListView {
    anchors.fill        : parent
    ScrollBar.vertical  : ScrollBar {
        anchors.rightMargin: 10 * AppTheme.scaleValue
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            color: "red"
        }
    }
    boundsBehavior      : Flickable.StopAtBounds
    currentIndex        : 0
    focus               : true
    clip                : true
    model               : 20
    delegate: Rectangle {
        id      : rect
        width   : parent.width
        height  : 50
        color   : index % 2 == 0 ? "#ECEEF1" : "#FFFFFF"
        Text {
            text                : index
            textFormat          : Text.StyledText
            color               : "red"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```